# Avoid evaluation of code inside c:if tag in JSTL

Tags: jsp, jsf, jstl

I need to use a template for various classes and I'm trying to avoid the evaluation of the code inside the c:if because the *bean* class has `getPrintResource()` only if is extending a specific class.

I'm trying

```
<c:if test="${bean instanceOf PrintableClass}">...

<c:if test="${! empty bean.printResource}">...
```

to avoid the evaluation of this element

```
<c:if test="${...}">
   <tag:printResource id="printBtn"
    rendered="#{bean.printable}"
    resource="#{bean.printResource}" 
       label="#{msg.print}">
   </tag:printResource>
</c:if>
```

The only result achieved is the `Property "printResource" not found on *bean*`

---

#### Edit

Even if I am able to build a valid test for the c:if, the attribute `resource` would be evaluated as `Property "printResource" not found`anyway.
My question is about avoiding the evaluation of a block of code if a test is false

---

Maybe my design is wrong or this isn't possible...
Thank you

Comment: Regarding your edit: the block inside the if won't be evaluated if the test is false, There shouldn't be any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom EL function that checks it. Something like

```
<c:if test="${myFn:isPrintResourcePossible(bean)}">
```

An EL function is just a static method in some class, declared in a tag library descriptor.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html for a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the bean is an instance of the expected class:

```
<c:if test="${bean.getClass().name =='my.package.PrintableClass'}">
```

Or another equivalent condition:

```
<c:if test="${bean['class'].simpleName eq 'PrintableClass'}">
```